# Not scrolling into view scrollIntoView scrollTo

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Why is not my element scrolled into view?

```
useEffect(() => {
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('some-class-name');
  const [element] = elements;
  if (element) {
     window.scrollTo(0, 0);
     element.scrollIntoView({ inline: 'center' });
  }
}, [aProp]);
```

It did work before, but now it does not work. I am using Chrome. Should not the container with horizontal scroll scroll the element into view? The reason I have the `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` is because I want the window to scroll to the top as well.

Comment: insert html and css

Comment: Are you certain the element with that class name exists? Also, what is the `useEffect` function? Could it be malfunctioning?

Comment: @PedroLima Yes, I am sure the class exist.
I do not think useEffect is making the mistake. The useEffect is a React function. It listens to a change in the value "aProp" and then it runs the function

Comment: @RMT, well, your function works for me and you said it used to work for you but stopped working for some reason, so it has to do with something you changed along the way. Can you provide more code?